# IIS FTP 7.5 creating nested directories

Tags: ftp

In FileZilla FTP Server I can do this: mkdir /parent/sub1/sub2
Which will create parent, sub1, and sub2 folders for me

However, I could not get same thing working in IIS FTP Server 7.5. Only if parent and sub1 already exist, then sub2 will be created. Otherwise the command fails.

In a basic Windows command prompt, mkdir a\b\c creates a, b, c folder just fine.

I tried with / and \ but no success.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have better luck posting this at http://www.serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks, I posted this questions there too. Really need some info on this. I cannot believe that IIS FTP has problems creating nested folders.